# Proving that conservation of momentum doesn't apply to electron in H-atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators, commutator

To prove that the conservation of linear momentum doesn't apply to electron in H-atom, is it sufficient to show that angular momentum operator ($\hat L$) and momentum operator ($\hat p$) do not commute?

Comment: The Hamiltonian conservation law is $[H,p] = 0$, not $[L,p] = 0$.

Comment: But in the $\ell = 0$ states of each $E_n$ level one has no angular momentum.

Answer (score 0):

That would only show that you cannot find simultaneous eigenstates of Linear and angular momentum. You could use Ehrenfest's theorem and show that the time derivative of the average of momentum is not zero.

Answer (score 0):

The ground state of the Hydrogen atom, $n=1, \ \ell = 0$, is an eigenstate of the angular momentum $\hat {\vec L}$ with eigenvalue zero. In this state we have

(1) $<n=1, \ \ell = 0| \hat {\vec L} \hat {\vec P} - \hat {\vec P} \hat {\vec L}|n=1, \ \ell = 0>$

$ \ \ \ \ = <n=1, \ \ell = 0|0 \dot \ \hat {\vec P} - \hat {\vec P} \dot \ 0| n=1, \ \ell = 0> = 0$.

These equalities show that in this state commutativity or non-commutativity of $\hat {\vec P}$ with the angular momentum operator has no meaning because of the eigenvalue zero of $\hat {\vec L}$.

So, I calculated the mean value of the linear momentum operator $\hat P = i \hbar \nabla$ for the ground state of the Hydrogen atom, and I obtained

(2) $< \hat P > \ = \ 0$.

However,

(3) $< \hat {P^2} > \ = \ \frac {\hbar ^2}{a_0^2}$,

where $a_0$ is the Bohr radius, (see the question [How did we come to know that electrons actually *move* in an atom?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/156498/how-did-we-come-to-know-that-electrons-actually-move-in-an-atom/156558#156558)).

Thus, by eq. (3) a linear movement exists in this state, but it is not a constant of motion, eq. (2).